# PHP secure writing to a text file?

Tags: php

An HTML form, a php file and a text file.

The form has one input box, it sends the inputted string to the PHP file using GET or POST.  The PHP file writes the string to the text file using `fopen 'a'`, `fwrite` and `fclose` and does no sanitization at all.

The text file is set to permission 777 and is in the same folder as the other files.

Are there any security concerns here?  Is it possible for someone to send something using the form that will do any damage?  If yes, what?

What about if the txt file is set to 666?

Comment: 6 for owner, 6 for group, and 6 for public

Comment: 777 allows read, write, and execute privileges to pretty much anyone and everyone. I'm guessing that might be of some concern to you! If it's a text file, 755 should be sufficient.

Comment: Why not 660 or 770? It depends on your server configuration.

Comment: as long as the user has no way to influence the file name you should not have any issues. provided, of course that this text file is an end destination for the data. don't use it for anything like database queries etc.

Comment: For the question I mean Can they send anything using the form that will be dangerous?  I have made the text file into a complicated name so no one will ever find it directly.  Just what can they send that is bad?  Like delete my server or something.

Comment: it may be possible to write php code into this text file using the form and execute it using a LFI vulnerability somewhere else.

Comment: @Mogria Yes, that is my main concern.  How can I sanitize against LFI vulnerabilities?

Comment: @David19801 The form itself as you describe it here is not vulnerable to LFI if you use a constant file name. But the problem is there might be an other script on the same server which is vulnerable to LFI.

Comment: @David19801 LFI attack happend if you include files based on a $_GET parameter, etc: www.domain.com?page=.htaccess . This can be bad. This is not directly connected to your form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Never execute

Depending on what the use of this file, there shouldn't be much risk involved. Just make sure the file is **never executed**.

This means, never `eval()` the content of this file, or change it into a `.php` or any other executable file.

However, if the content is ever to be written on a page, or viewable by the user, you will have security risks doing this.

Comment: If I can open it in a browser (because it is a .txt file), is that bad?  I check the contents every day using a browser window...can they send me a virus?

Comment: No, the content will not be executed as a .txt file, this should be safe.

Answer (score 1):

I typically use 3 ways to improve security writing to files. 1) Move file out of webroot and into some folder with restricted access like cgi-bin. The path to the file and any passwords should also be saved outside of the webroot. 2) Then you include the sensitive data by including it on your page. So if PHP parser fails people only see a variable name and no details. 3) If your are doing a post or get to the file which is doing the writing you can also check the values carefully and stip out characters, script, etc. that could cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

From a web-security point of view, I do not see any problems, as long as the path of the text file is hardcoded or secured in any other way. You haven't said anything though about what happens if the file is missing or read-only (yes, it can happen, for example if the file system is mounted read-only by the administrator).

That being said, this use case is also completely useless, as the text file serves only as a data sink. A data sink that is never read from is useless. The problems may arise when you want to read from the file.

Comment: Could someone send php code in the input form that gets to the .txt file and then they run the .txt file?  Can php code run from a .txt file on a server?

Comment: @David19801 if your server is configured correctly, this should be no concern. Apache for example limits PHP execution by extension.

Comment: where do I check on the server which extensions php can execture in?